# New action and rendering partial sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Problem: Can't use "new" action in my sign up partial. I get `"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty".`

I have mapped out my Users model to be restful. In my `application.html.erb` my Sign Up renders a bootstrap modal (A Sign Up popup window rather then rendering a new page) The modal is pre rendered in the `application.html.erb`.

Now I can partially see where the problem is coming from I'll get to that in a second. In my **Users controller** I have:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  render :partial => 'users/sign_up_modal'
end
```

As well as in the **new.html.erb** I have:

```
<%= render "users/sign_up_modal" %>
```

So I realize that I'm rending the partial but I haven't called for the new action, I know I could have the new action which then renders the partial but that defeats the purpose of the popup window and instead renders a new page /new..

So I'm in the hopes that someone may be able to help me solve this problem.. It's doing my head in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Suggest you use [`locals`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials) in `sign_up_modal` partial and call your partial as

```
<%= render :partial => "users/sign_up_modal" ,:locals=>{:user=> @user || User.new} %>
```

It's just like passing parameters to a method.

in you   `users/sign_up_modal` you will use this `user` object like:

```
<%=form_for user do |f|%>
  #What ever the form is
<%end%>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! Unfortunately just like every other answer on here I still get the same error: 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'. Still trying to figure out why...

Comment: Can you please update your question with code snippet of your partial/view 'users/sign_up_modal'

Comment: Actually... I tried this again and it worked! I forgot to delete something. 

But will using this and calling user as a local variable mean that later down the track when I want to add methods and arguments involving User.new from the new action. Will this mean this action will not be available and usable through the users_controller?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Controller/Action if you wanna use this partial in your NEW action then simply call this partial in your 'users/new.html.erb' view and provide the @user as local variable. Further visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials for more guide. If you need more guidance then feel free to ask

Comment: Hi, so how would I go about using a Create controller/action with the partial? Because In order for users to sign up I will have to link it to the Create controller/action.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're presumably pulling this partial through Ajax or without the action, it needs to have the `@instance_variable` available.

The simplest solution is to invoke a new instance of the class in the form itself:

```
#app/views/users/_sign_up_modal.html.erb
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

--

Of course, you could also set the variable through the `ApplicationController` (inefficient):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :set_user

   private

   def set_user
      @user = User.new
   end
end
```

The most succinct & efficient solution is the one by `@Qaisar Nadeem` - passing a "local" variable to your form, so the variable is available each time.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.. I tried the locals method however still failure... I know User.new would work but that defeats the purpose of the restful architecture...

Comment: "defeats the purpose of the restful architecture" You could argue including value-dependent partials does the same?

Answer (score 1):

Partials are used to share code between views - thus you would never render a partial from your controller - just from other views.

Modals are kind of special case - if you are simply using a modal form on your root page than it does not really have anything to do with your `users/new` route or the `UsersController#new` action.

Rather you might want to have `users/new` display the form the classical sense and share the actual form contents with the modal:

The partial `app/views/users/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
   <%- # ... a bunch of inputs -%>
   <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`app/views/users/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= render partial: 'form', user: @user %>
```

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render partial: 'form', user: User.new %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason you may want to have both is that modals usually tend to have accessibility problems and will often not work as well cross platform as intended (bootstrap is no exception here). For something as important as signup you should offer the user an alternative where half the form is not stuck outside the screen. Popup blockers can also cause issues.

You new method would look like this:

```
def new 
  @user = User.new 
  # rails renders 'new.html.erb' by convention. Magic!
end
```